# expo build:android apk crashes after splash screen

Tags: react-native, expo

I have created an app in React Native / Expo. It works fine during development but is crashing when I create a standalone app (expo build:android)

The splash screen gets displayed and then directly the app crashes.

This is not an issue of the Expo CLI, because I tried to build other apps and they seem to work fine.

My package.json file

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@bugsnag/expo": "^7.12.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/hooks": "^2.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "6.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.13",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.3.5",
    "apisauce": "^2.1.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.6",
    "expo": "~42.0.1",
    "expo-blur": "~9.0.3",
    "expo-constants": "^11.0.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~10.2.2",
    "expo-jwt": "^1.4.1",
    "expo-location": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.12.3",
    "expo-secure-store": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "jwt-encode": "^1.0.1",
    "lottie-react-native": "4.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-expo-image-cache": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-image-slider-banner": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-image-slider-box": "^1.1.22",
    "react-native-image-slider-with-text": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.0.12",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "yup": "^0.28.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "xxx",
    "slug": "xxx",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./app/assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./app/assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "extra": {
    "bugsnag": {
      "apiKey": "dff242972ecc8c9bbe9d5f36fac4d2d9"
    }
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier" : "com.xxx.xx",
      "buildNumber" : "1.0.0"

    },
    "android": {
      "package" : "com.xxx.xx",
      "versionCode" : 1,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./app/assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./app/assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "description": ""
  }
}
```

============            UPDATED SECTION ==================

I have google search for the solution and made some modification then I ran into another problem after running

**expo start --no-dev --minify**

I ran into few more issue

Sometime it throw
-- Failed to load all asset
[image: Fail to load all asset]
-- Sometime I get ..Could not connect to development server.
[image]
Can somebody please help me to figure out this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Please take a look at  and post logs from Android Studio logcat while you are running the app in production

Comment: @sushrut619 I have updated my question can you please look into updated section and help. I have been searching for the solution but no success..